# How to convert a string to utf-8 in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I have a browser which sends utf-8 characters to my Python server, but when I retrieve it from the query string, the encoding that Python returns is ASCII. How can I convert the plain string to utf-8?

NOTE: The string passed from the web is already UTF-8 encoded, I just want to make Python to treat it as UTF-8 not ASCII.

Comment: Try this link
[http://evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html](http://evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html)

Comment: I think a better title would be **How to coerce a string to unicode without translation?**

Comment: In 2018, python 3 if you get ascii decode error do `"some_string".encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 316, accepted):

#### In Python 2

```
>>> plain_string = "Hi!"
>>> unicode_string = u"Hi!"
>>> type(plain_string), type(unicode_string)
(<type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>)
```

^ This is the difference between a byte string (plain_string) and a unicode string.

```
>>> s = "Hello!"
>>> u = unicode(s, "utf-8")
```

^ Converting to unicode and specifying the encoding.

#### In Python 3

All strings are unicode. The `unicode` function does not exist anymore. See answer from @Noumenon

Comment: ,I am getting the following error:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 2: invalid start byte`
This is my code:
    ret=[]

    for line in csvReader:
        cline=[]
        for elm in line:
            unicodestr = unicode(elm, 'utf-8')
            cline.append(unicodestr)
        ret.append(cline)

Comment: None of this applies in Python 3, all strings are unicode and `unicode()` doesn't exist.

Comment: Kind of bumping this, but thanks. This fixed an issue where I was trying to print unicode and was getting �s.

Comment: How to you convert `u` back to a `str` format (convert `u` back to `s`)?

Comment: This code will only work as long as the text does not contain non-ascii characters; a simple accented character on the string will make it fail.

Comment: Hi, if you have `"2340"` in a string variable, and you want to print the unicode character `U+2340` (⍀), is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Sha2b `chr(0x2340)` gives: `⍀`

Answer (score 84):

If the methods above don't work, you can also tell Python to ignore portions of a string that it can't convert to utf-8:

```
stringnamehere.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

Comment: Got AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: @saran3h it sounds like you're using Python 3, in which case Python *should* handle encoding issues for you. Have you tried reading your document without specifying an encoding?

Comment: Python by default picks system encoding. In windows 10 it's cp1252 which is different from utf-8. I wasted few hours on it while using codecs.open() in py 3.8

Answer (score 25):

Might be a bit overkill, but when I work with ascii and unicode in same files, repeating decode can be a pain, this is what I use:

```
def make_unicode(inp):
    if type(inp) != unicode:
        inp =  inp.decode('utf-8')
    return inp
```

Comment: This no longer works, as written... the `unicode` type doesn't exist in python3

Answer (score 16):

Adding the following line to the top of your .py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

allows you to encode strings directly in your script, like this:

```
utfstr = "ボールト"
```

Comment: It is not what OP asks. But avoid such string literals anyway. It creates Unicode string in Python 3 (good) but it is a bytestring in Python 2 (bad). Either add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top or use `u''` prefix. Don't use non-ascii characters in `bytes` literals. To get utf-8 bytes, you could `utf8bytes = unicode_text.encode('utf-8')` later if it is necessary.

Comment: @jfs how will  `from __future__ import unicode_literals` help me to convert a string with non-ascii characters to utf-8?

Comment: @OrtalTurgeman I'm not answering the question. Look, it is a comment, not an answer. My comment addresses the issue with the code in the answer. It tries to create a bytestring with non-ascii characters on Python 2 (it is a SyntaxError on Python 3 — bytes literals forbid that).

Answer (score 15):

```
city = 'Ribeir\xc3\xa3o Preto'
print city.decode('cp1252').encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 13):

If I understand you correctly, you have a utf-8 encoded byte-string in your code.

Converting a byte-string to a unicode string is known as decoding (unicode -> byte-string is encoding).

You do that by using the [unicode](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode) function or the [decode](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) method. Either:

```
unicodestr = unicode(bytestr, encoding)
unicodestr = unicode(bytestr, "utf-8")
```

Or:

```
unicodestr = bytestr.decode(encoding)
unicodestr = bytestr.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 13):

In Python 3.6, they do not have a built-in unicode() method.
Strings are already stored as unicode by default and no conversion is required. Example:

```
my_str = "\u221a25"
print(my_str)
>>> √25
```

Answer (score 5):

Translate with ord() and unichar().
Every unicode char have a number asociated, something like an index. So Python have a few methods to translate between a char and his number. Downside is a ñ example. Hope it can help.

```
>>> C = 'ñ'
>>> U = C.decode('utf8')
>>> U
u'\xf1'
>>> ord(U)
241
>>> unichr(241)
u'\xf1'
>>> print unichr(241).encode('utf8')
ñ
```

Answer (score 5):

The url is translated to ASCII and to the Python server it is just a Unicode string, eg.:
"T%C3%A9st%C3%A3o"

Python understands "é" and "ã" as actual %C3%A9 and %C3%A3.

You can encode an URL just like this:

```
import urllib
url = "T%C3%A9st%C3%A3o"
print(urllib.parse.unquote(url))
>> Téstão
```

See https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-decode-a-utf-8-url-in-python for details.

Answer (score 4):

- First, `str` in Python is represented in `Unicode`.
- Second, `UTF-8` is an encoding standard to encode `Unicode` string to `bytes`. There are many encoding standards out there (e.g. `UTF-16`, `ASCII`, `SHIFT-JIS`, etc.).

When the client sends data to your server and they are using `UTF-8`, they are sending a bunch of `bytes` not `str`.

You received a `str` because the "library" or "framework" that you are using, has implicitly converted some random `bytes` to `str`.

Under the hood, there is just a bunch of `bytes`. You just need ask the "library" to give you the request content in `bytes` and you will handle the decoding yourself (if library can't give you then it is trying to do black magic then you shouldn't use it).

- Decode `UTF-8` encoded `bytes` to `str`: `bs.decode('utf-8')`
- Encode `str` to `UTF-8` `bytes`: `s.encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's standard library [`codecs` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html).

```
import codecs
codecs.decode(b'Decode me', 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
unidecode(yourStringtoDecode)
```

Comment: What is `unidecode`? Is it this https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode? Please provide info if it's a 3rd-party package, and how to install/use it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can add

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in your source code's first line.

You can read more details here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/