# Unicode regex to match a character class of Chinese characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

`^[一二三四五六七]、` doesn't match `一、`

But  `^一、`  matches `一、`.

Is my way of specifying a character class of Chinese characters wrong?

I read the regular expression from a file.

Comment: Are you specifying the characters in a unicode string or a byte string?  What is the encoding of the file containing your code?

Comment: "the encoding of your file?" you mean my python script file? Where do you specify  the encoding of  file?

Answer (score 3):

Works for me,

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(u'^[一二三四五六七]、', u'一、')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='一、'>
>>> re.match(u'^[一二三四五六七]、', u'一、').group(0)
'一、'
```

I think you failed to define your regex as unicode string.

In python3, it would be

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

with open('file') as f:
    reg = f.read().strip()
    print(re.match(reg, u'一、').group(0))
```

Comment: Does adding `u` also work for those cases which do not need `u`?

Comment: Also I read the regex from a text file by `myregex=open('myfile').read()`, where `myfile` content is `^[一二三四五六七]、`. How can I specify `u` then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/python-how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8

Comment: It seems the replies there all specify the strings in Python scripts. I would like to know how to treat a regex read from a text file as `u`?

Comment: I am in Python 2.7. Both regex and the text are read from (different) text files

Comment: Always mention the version of python you're running.. Your question fails to provide these details..

Comment: `u'一、'` seems to be invalid syntax in Python 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you read the files using the correct encoding:

```
with open('my-regex-file', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    regex = re.compile(f.read())
with open('my-text-file', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
if regex.match(text):
    print("It's a match!")
```