# How to specify string variables as unicode strings for pattern and text in regex matching?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, unicode

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(u'^[一二三四五六七]、', u'一、')
```

If the pattern and the text are stored in variables (for example, they were read from text files),

```
>>> myregex='^[一二三四五六七]、'
>>> mytext='一、'
```

How shall I specify `myregex` and `mytext` to `re.match`, in the same way as `re.match(u'^[一二三四五六七]、', u'一、')`? Thanks.

Comment: Your working example uses Unicode strings while your non-working example uses byte strings and that's wrong in your case.

Comment: Did you just create a duplicate of [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857742/unicode-regex-to-match-a-character-class-of-chinese-characters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use

```
re.match(myregex.decode('utf-8'), mytext.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't match anything. while `re.match(u'^[一二三四五六七]、', u'一、')` does.

Comment: When is `re.U` needed then?