# What is a good strategy when it comes to Python I/O and user input from command prompt?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, io, character-encoding

I am freaking out lately because I have spent a week writing a totally useless pyton module that transforms some spacial data to a .csv format.

I got not problemwith handling the spatial data but when the software runs I ask the user to submit some input from the command prompt or cygwin. After a lot of effort and googling I got it somehow to work with UTF-8.

I made the compromise to use only english language and not (greek) that I needed but now I get errors about english! Take a look at the error:

```
Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' or 'y' or 'n').
Would you like to add trips to the route with id ''no5leho'' and direction 0?
[y/n] y
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 296, in <module>
inputAddTrips = query_yes_no('Would you like to add trips to the route with id \'\'%s\'\' and direction 0?\r\n' % (i))
File "main.py", line 33, in query_yes_no
choice = input().lower()
File "C:\Python34\lib\codecs.py", line 319, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

I have tried all sorts of try like setting PYTHONIOENCODING system variable to utf-8 and .encoding decoding every single print and input().

I have used

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But nothing happens? I still get those errors! So I want to ask what you guys do when it comes to input and output? I am a begineer but I know that big websites and software are made in Python so there must be a way to aboid all those errors!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Greek or English. It's about encoding in general. If a user submits something encoding comes from the system. Most likely it is neither UTF-8, nor ASCII. Your error is "invalid continuation byte" that indicates ISO-8859-1. Maybe this tread will be helpful? [UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552555/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-continuation-byte)

Comment: In my case the user  submits data from command prompt or cygwin. Since I have changed character encoding in both to be utf-8 is there any other place where something changes the encoding?

Comment: From the system locale, I guess.

Comment: system locale was allways at the right place.Anyway , thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [python: how to convert a string to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/python-how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8), you could convert to unicode and specify the encoding as `utf-8` and, failing that, you could tell python to ignore portions of a string that it can't convert to utf-8 with some basic error handling.

Comment: well what happens to the ignored errors? they are not shown at all? I don't want this. I am so dissapointed with python not being able to handle that basic stuff. This is basic I/O stuff.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, I'd really have to see more than what you have provided, and I don't know what kind of data you are getting in. However, to find out what kind of encoding you are dealing with, you can use [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet). Let' say the encoding is latin-1, then the following might work: `s.decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8")`, where s is the input you are dealing with. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644099/python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte) for more details.

Comment: I am ok with the "weid" data. I have a problem when I enter names from the command prompt! Both command prompt and python seem to use utf-8 but I get this error above!

Comment: I meant to say weird* data

Comment: That's annoying alright! The above post seems helpful though, and as a Linux user I can't be of any more help in dealing with problems related to Windows. You should definitely check out the following link too, it's quite useful: [http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: No problem, hope you get the problem sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with PYTHONIOENCODING.  It's for making Python output a particular encoding ignoring what the console actually supports and is used when using the command shell to redirect Python output to a file in a particular encoding.

Windows consoles don't do UTF-8 well. Since you wanted Greek, what is your code page?  Code page 737 is a Greek encoding.  You also need a console font that supports Greek characters.  I'm using Consolas font.

I'm on US Windows which defaults to code page 437.  Switch to Greek:

```
C:\>chcp 737
Active code page: 737
```

Display all the characters supported by the code page:

```
C:\>py
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> bytes(range(256)).decode('cp737')
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\
x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7fΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠ
ΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρσςτυφχψ░▒▓│┤╡╢╖╕╣║╗╝╜╛┐└┴┬├─┼╞╟╚╔╩╦╠═╬╧╨╤╥╙╘╒╓╫╪┘┌█▄▌▐▀ωάέήϊίόύϋώΆΈΉΊΌΎΏ±≥≤ΪΫ÷≈°∙·√ⁿ²■\xa0'
```

Ask for some input using Greek characters.  I just cut-and-pasted some supported characters, but if your Windows is configured for Greek you should be able to type directly:

```
>>> input('Greek? ')
Greek? ΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαβγδεζηθ
'ΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩαβγδεζηθ'
>>>
```

Another option is to skip using the Windows console and get a decent Python IDE that supports UTF-8.

Comment: hey thanks for answering! Aren't greek included in utf-8? If yes, why should I use 737 ? What IDE do you suggest? Some say komodo some eclipse with a a plugin!

Comment: Yes, UTF8 contains all of Unicode, but it is the Windows console that doesn't support it well. It's code page 65001 if you want to try it.

Comment: I get the second option but what is the first option you suggest?

Comment: You've not given enough information to see how you get those errors.  Whatever you have done to use UTF-8 isn't correct.  Update your question with the code and steps to reproduce your problem and then I can suggest how to use the first option.