# ZMQ Socket TypeError: unicode strings only Error: is there a fix?

Tags: python, sockets, typeerror, pyzmq

Trying to run the following Python code in command prompt:
I'm using Python 2.

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect('tcp://0.0.0.0.:6667')
socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, 'value')
```

and getting the following error when I execute:

> ```
> socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, value)   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 192, in >set_string
> raise TypeError("unicode strings only") TypeError: unicode strings only
> ```

can you pls advise on a solution ?

Comment: So, have you tried passing [Unicode string](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) to `setsockopt_string()`?

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/python-how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8

Comment: I have tried all suggested methods in https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

Comment: Just use python 3 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.setsockopt_string` accepts `unicode` string for optval.

if you only run your code in python2, you should use

`sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b"value")`

if you want to support both python2 and python3, you could use

```
try:
    sock.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'value')
except TypeError:
    sock.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'value')
```

Take a look at http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unicode.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately - still "unicode strings only"