# Errno 22 invalid mode w+ or filename

Tags: python

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+') or filename: 'hodor_2017-05-09_14:03:38.txt'
```

So I was having issues creating a file where as it is "name" [delimiter] "datetime" .txt

I was looking up different bits of code such as:

[Turn a string into a valid filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295135/turn-a-string-into-a-valid-filename)

[python: how to convert a string to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/python-how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8)

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/safestring.py

and it still seems to not work for me.

My concept is simple:  given a name and content write a file with that name and that content.

My code is:

```
def create_json_file(name, contents):
    filename = u"%s_%s.json" % (name, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S"))
    print "%s" % filename
    filename = slugify(filename)
    f = open(filename, "w+")
    f.write(contents)
    f.close()
```

and as you can see i have been tweaking it.  I was looking up the results that django does, which uses slugify.

My original did not have that line.  Maybe there is a better way to name the file too.  I think the name and datetime is pretty normal but i wasnt sure what delimiters I should be using between name and datetime etc.

For the record, I am not currently using Django because i dont have a need for the framework.  I am just trying to test a way to pass in a string and a json map and turn it into a `config.json` file essentially.

Eventually, I will want to leverage an AJAX request from a website to do this, but that is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Doesn't this just boil down to Windows disallowing colons in file names? The solution is to use a different separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a different separator in your filename mask:

```
filename = u"%s_%s.json" % (name, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S"))
```

The OS is trying to open 2005/04/01_5:45:04.json.  Slashes aren't allowed in file/directory names.

Edit: Removed colons in response to comments.

Comment: On Windows, neither are colons. Might think about moving to ISO 8601 basic format -- `%Y%m%dT%H%M%S`, no colons, no slashes, `T` separating the date portion and the time portion... and, well, it's an actual standard.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I knew about slashes, for some reason i was stupid and wasnt thinking the colon.  my bad.   Yeah, I will likely just use isoformat()

Comment: @CharlesDuffy just a follow up, doing it in iso format returns this error `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+') or filename: u'hodor_2017-05-10T10:23:07.057000.
json'` So it seems it wont do standard ISO, so i moved it to your format.  It seems the ISO 8601 used by default with Python's string class is: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmm`.  Doing it with the specific format you defined works though.

Comment: @Fallenreaper, right -- that's why I specified ISO 8601 **basic**, as opposed to ISO 8601 extended (which has the colons and dashes).

Comment: yeah, i just wanted to make a public note that isoString function for Python's Datetime would not return the ISO8601 basic format, but the extended, So its required to  use some a formatter