# How convert a string contain unicode characters to UTF in python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have a string contains Unicode characters and I want to convert it to UTF-8 in python.

```py
s = '\u0628\u06cc\u0633\u06a9\u0648\u06cc\u062a'
```

I want convert s to UTF format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string to utf-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `u` as prefix for the string `s` then encode it in `utf-8`.

Your code will look like this:

```
s = u'\u0628\u06cc\u0633\u06a9\u0648\u06cc\u062a'
s_encoded = s.encode('utf-8')
print(s_encoded)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: If the OP is using Python 3 (it seems so), then the `u` prefix isn't necessary. But the `.encode('utf8')` is definitely right.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in the top of your .py file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

It allows you to encode strings directly in your python script, like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = '\u0628\u06cc\u0633\u06a9\u0648\u06cc\u062a'
print(s)
```

Output :

```
بیسکویت
```

Comment: The source encoding declaration doesn't really apply here, because the string is entered with ASCII-only characters. It would be different if the string literal was actually composed of Arabic letters (not escape sequences).

Comment: A coding line declares the encoding of the *source file* only.  If you have only ASCII characters in the source (as above) it does nothing.  In fact, in Python 3, UTF-8 is the default source encoding if undeclared.