# Convert String into the format that readUTF() expects

Tags: java, python, sockets, utf-8

I created a Client with Java and a Server with Python. The Java client receive data using readUTF() of the class DataInputStream. My problem is that the function readUTF() expects a modified version of 'utf-8' that I don't know how to generate in the (Python) server side.

Comment: Why do you not simply use regular utf-8 for the interface? Instead of readUTF() you should use a stream-reader class with strings and characters instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually `encode()` your python string with the appropriate format.

[How to convert a string to utf-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8-in-python)

Comment: My problem is not with encoding into utf-8 I can just send something like b'test', my problem is with the specific modified version of utf-8 that readUTF() function expects...

Answer (score 0):

I got it!. Using the function read() of the class DataInputStream do work. The problem was that I initialized the destination buffer like this: byte[] ans = {}, instead of allocating some bytes. Thanks for everyone!