# Unicode for an emoji in a string variable isn't shown as the emoji

Tags: python, unicode, emoji, python-unicode, python-3.9

First of all, sorry for my poor and approximate english...

I'm trying to do a Python script, who should **retrieve a variable** that will represent the **unicode code corresponding to an emoji** (U000xxxx).
The final goal of this part of the program is to have translated, from unicode, in the name of the emoji.

Since I know that in Python to display an emoji it is `print("\U000XXXXX")`
, so I added the `\` before the previous name.
But when I print the final rendering is not the one expected

```
unicode = "U0001f0cf"
unicode = (f"\{unicode}") #OR# unicode = "\%s" %unicode
print (unicode) #>>> \U0001f0cf
#Expected >>>
```

I tried a lot of things including `.encode()` but Python told me I *couldn't use a string pattern on an object of type bytes* (?)

This is the part that is causing me problem, all the rest of the process is ok...
To translate the name of the emoji, from unicode, I found this method (crafted from another Stackoverflow topic)

```py
name = emojis.decode(unicode).replace("_"," ").replace(":","")
print(name) #>>> \U0001f0cf
```

Whereas if I directly enter the unicode code it works...

```py
name = emojis.decode("U0001f0cf").replace("_"," ").replace(":","")
print(name) #>>> :black_joker:
```

Thank you very much to anyone who will try to help me,
Have a good evening

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert in utf16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62821643/convert-in-utf16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the numeric part from the variable, then use `chr()` to convert it to its Unicode equivalent, then use the `unicodedata` database to fetch its name:

```py
import unicodedata as ud

u = 'U0001f0cf'
i = int(u[1:],16)
c = chr(i)
n = ud.name(c)
print(c,n)
```

Output:

```
 PLAYING CARD BLACK JOKER
```

You can also use a range loop to display a number of emoji:

```py
import unicodedata as ud

for i in range(0x1f0c1,0x1f0d0):
    c = chr(i)
    n = ud.name(c)
    print(c,n)
```

Output:

```
 PLAYING CARD ACE OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD TWO OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD THREE OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD FOUR OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD FIVE OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD SIX OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD SEVEN OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD EIGHT OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD NINE OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD TEN OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD JACK OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD KNIGHT OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD QUEEN OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD KING OF DIAMONDS
 PLAYING CARD BLACK JOKER
```

Answer (score 3):

```
unicode = "U0001f0cf"
unicode = (f"\{unicode}")

print(unicode.encode('raw-unicode-escape').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

This gives you  instead of `\U0001f0cf`

Answer (score 3):

You are confused about the meaning of the backslash. In Python source code, `"\U0001f0cf"` encodes a single character in a string. You can't turn the nine-character string `"U0001f0cf"` into a single character by adding a backslash in front, any more that concatenating a literal backslash in front of `"n"` turns it into a newline.

What you *can* do easily is drop the `U` and convert that hex number into a character via `chr()`.

```py
unicode = "U0001f0cf"
print(chr(int(unicode[1:], 16)))
```

`int("string", base)` converts `string` to a number in the specified `base`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` for this.

We can build a valid string literal containing a unicode escape sequence for python. We just have to add `"`.

```
from ast import literal_eval

user_input = 'U0001f0cf'
emoji_literal = f'"\\{user_input}"'
#                 ^              ^
#                here         and here
print(emoji_literal)   # prints "\U0001f0cf"
repaired_emoji = literal_eval(emoji_literal)
print(repaired_emoji)  # prints
```

The `emoji_literal` contains `"\U0001f0cf"` which is exactly what you would type in when you didn't have a variable.

`ast.literal_eval` then interprets the string as if we used it as a string literal in python.

Comment: Thank you ! Is there a difference between the solution you proposed (using `literal_eval()`) and that of Kesslwovv which just uses `eval()`?

Comment: `litteral_eval` is safer. the built-in documentation of python (`help()` in the python shell) states: `literal_eval(node_or_string): Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.`

Answer (score -2):

the simple way of getting the unicode character is to include the backslash in the first place:

```
unicode = "\U0001f0cf"
print (unicode) #>>>
```

the other way is more complex and a bit ugly due to the use of `eval`:

```
unicode = "U0001f0cf"
unicode = eval(f'"\\{unicode}"')
print(unicode) #>>>
```

in this case `f'"\\{unicode}"'` is evaluated to `'"\U0001f0cf"'` and the string inside the f-string is evaluated (`"\U0001f0cf"` to `).

edit (because of tripleee's comment):

`eval` is insecure when used with user input because the user can evaluate any code (including os-commands). but as long as you only use the code for yourself, this is not an issue.
alternatives are:

- `ast.literal_eval` like in Wombatz answer for safe-evaluating
- `chr` like in tripleee's answer, which is a very elegant and fitting solution.

Comment: **Thank you so much !** My lack of knowledge of basic functions, yet essential, failed me again.
It works very well, I will report the topic as resolved, with your simple and explained answer :))

Comment: Please don't recommend `eval`. There are much simpler and less insecure ways to do this.

Comment: why is it "insecure"? @tripleee

Comment: [Why is using `eval` a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940)