# Python to open and save csv file in Apache OpenOffice

Tags: python, openoffice.org

I want to know is there any solution to
1)use python to launch apache open office
2)open an csv file
3)Auto fill in Text Import
4)then save it into xls file.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice.exe')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why do you want to open OpenOffice with Python. But you can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library to read csv and convert it to excel file.

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_csv (r'Path where the CSV file is stored\File name.csv')
read_file.to_excel (r'Path to store the Excel file\File name.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: Hi Misterlen, Can I set the Text Import Option such as change character set to utf-8, seperator options to comma, and change all fields to text, is it possible to implement that?

Comment: You can modify or manipulate the data using pandas library and or other python libraries. read [deal with unicode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#dealing-with-unicode-data) or [convert char to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8-in-python)