# Display Japanese characters in Visual Studio Code using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, utf-8

According to [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182635/11808605), Python 3 strings are UTF-8 compliant by default. But in my web scraper using BeautifulSoup, when I try to print or display a URL, the Japanese characters show up as '%E3%81%82' or '%E3%81%B3' instead of the actual characters.

[This Japanese website](https://kokugo.jitenon.jp/cat/gojuonindex.php) is the one I'm collecting information from, more specifically the URLs that correspond with the links in the clickable letter buttons. When you hover over for example あa, your browser will show you that the link you're about to click on is `https://kokugo.jitenon.jp/cat/gojuon.php?word=あ`. However, extracting the `["href"]` property of the link using BeautifulSoup, I get `https://kokugo.jitenon.jp/cat/gojuon.php?word=%E3%81%82`.

Both versions link to the same web page, but for the sake of debugging, I'm wondering if it's possible to make sure the displayed string contains the actual Japanese character. If not, how can I convert the string to accommodate this purpose?

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I made a dictionary where the keys are the messed up character representations (with the percent signs) and the values are the corresponding Japanese characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding):

> *Percent-encoding*, also known as *URL encoding*, is a method to encode arbitrary data in a [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (URI)
> using only the limited US-ASCII characters legal within a URI.

Apply the [`unquote` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) from [`urllib.parse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

> ```
> urllib.parse.unquote(string, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
> ```
>
> Replace `%xx` escapes by their single-character equivalent. The
> optional encoding and errors parameters specify how to decode
> percent-encoded sequences into Unicode characters, as accepted by the
> `bytes.decode()` method.
>
> `string` must be a `str`. *Changed in version 3.9*: `string` parameter
> supports `bytes` and `str` objects (previously only `str`).
>
> `encoding` defaults to `'utf-8'`. `errors` defaults to `'replace'`,
> meaning invalid sequences are replaced by a placeholder character.

**Example**:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
encodedUrl = 'JapaneseChars%E3%81%82or%E3%81%B3'
decodedUrl = unquote( encodedUrl )
print( decodedUrl )
```

> ```
> JapaneseCharsあorび
> ```

One can apply the `unquote` method to almost any string, even if already decoded:

```
print( unquote(decodedUrl) )
```

> ```
> JapaneseCharsあorび
> ```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! As a follow-up, does the percent-encoding occur when the data gets scraped from the website, or when Python tries to display it?