# How to use different unicode in python if the output is in different languages that does not have latin unicode?

Tags: python, tkinter, unicode

I'm doing a code for language translator app using tkinter and as an extra feature, I decided to add a function which lets you save the translated text as a pdf file. The problem is, if the translated text contains characters outside of latin unicode, I get errors.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vinit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/vinit/PycharmProjects/LanguageTranslator/Translator/Translator.py", line 66, in savepdf
    pdf.output("Language.pdf")
  File "C:\Users\vinit\PycharmProjects\LanguageTranslator\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1065, in output
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\vinit\PycharmProjects\LanguageTranslator\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 246, in close
    self._enddoc()
  File "C:\Users\vinit\PycharmProjects\LanguageTranslator\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1636, in _enddoc
    self._putpages()
  File "C:\Users\vinit\PycharmProjects\LanguageTranslator\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1170, in _putpages
    p = self.pages[n].encode("latin1") if PY3K else self.pages[n]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 87-91: ordinal not in range(256)
```

How do I go about so that if I want to translate text from English to Hindi or any other language that has different characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to utf-8 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unicode font should be set up and used by using `.add_font()`.

Below is an example code of using `arialuni.ttf`:

```py
...
pdf.add_font("arialuni", "", "C:/Windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf", uni=True)
pdf.set_font("arialuni", size=15)
...
```

Details can be referred to [document](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Unicode/index.html).